# How to find the input that provides the minimum value for a list of function values?

Tags: python

I have written a function that calculates the cost for energy consumption given the capacity of a solar panel, and certain energy demand and production values that are randomly taken from a normal distribution using np.random.randn. I then have another function where I run the function a bunch of times and calculate the average cost for the given capacity. I want to write a function that will run the average cost function for a bunch of different values for the capacity and I want this function to then return the battery capacity that gives the minimum average cost out of all the average costs calculated in the simulation.

What I've done so far is use a for loop to run the average cost function multiple times for each different capacity value, and I've stored each of these values in a list. I know that I can find the minimum value from this list by just using the min function, but I'm not quite sure how to then return the capacity that is associated with that minimum cost

Comment: The [`argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) function returns the index of the minimum value, which you can then use to get the associated value from the capacity array.

Comment: can u provide code so we can take look and help u more

Comment: The answer to your question will have nothing to do with solar panels and batteries, so try to make your question-text shorter and purely about the mathematical problem and it will be easier to read/find.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can try to help you with your code

Comment: loop though the list of parameters and keep track of the minimum result and the parameter that gave you that result. If you find a new minimum result update those variables accordingly.